# Bigquery, counting unique records in X time frame grouped by day

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, ansi-sql

With a dataset that is ID, DateTime with a high degree of duplication. What is the best way to approach counting the first instance of a unique ID for a window? For instance 5 minutes and 20 minutes?

Data

```
1, 2022-09-26 20:00:00.000000
1, 2022-09-26 20:01:00.000000
1, 2022-09-26 20:02:00.000000
1, 2022-09-26 20:03:00.000000
1, 2022-09-26 20:04:00.000000
1, 2022-09-26 20:05:00.000000
1, 2022-09-26 20:06:00.000000
1, 2022-09-26 20:07:00.000000
1, 2022-09-26 20:08:00.000000
1, 2022-09-26 20:09:00.000000
2, 2022-09-26 20:00:00.000000
2, 2022-09-26 20:01:00.000000
2, 2022-09-26 20:02:00.000000
2, 2022-09-26 20:03:00.000000
2, 2022-09-26 20:04:00.000000
2, 2022-09-26 20:05:00.000000
2, 2022-09-26 20:06:00.000000
2, 2022-09-26 20:07:00.000000
2, 2022-09-26 20:08:00.000000
2, 2022-09-26 20:09:00.000000
```

Result 5 min window count of 4 uniques (2 of each id since there are 2 5 min windows in the data)

```
2022-09-26, 4
```

Result 20 min window count of 2 uniques, 1 of each id

```
2022-09-26, 2
```

I thought I could do it with partioning and rownumber but that is not working. I am not sure what the right approach is?

Comment: Just to clarify, for the 5 min window, which rows qualified for each id? Same with the 20 min window.

Comment: @RiccoD the minutes 00 and 05 for each ID would be counted as uniques for the 5 minute window the rest ignored as dupes within the 5 minute window (having no previous counted record for the last 5 min). For the 20 minute window only the 00 minute records for each id would be counted all others are duplicates in the 20 minute window.